# Cucumber feature writing feedback

Tags: testing, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber, bdd

So I'm trying to develop a website using Ruby on Rails and I'm new to the concept of BDD. I've worked through both the Ruby on Rails Tutorial and the RSpec book and starting to strike out on my own, but was hoping to get some feedback on an initial feature.

```
Feature: User Signup

As a user (anyone who may use the system, to include persons outside the unit)
I want to sign up 
So that I can access the website

Scenario: sign up
    Given I have not yet signed up
    When I go the signup page
    Then I should be redirected to the signup page
```

Am I on the right track here..?

Comment: The scenario doesn't seem to make sense. Going to the sign-up page redirects to the sign-up page?

Comment: Does "When I click the signup link" make more sense? I was picturing it as a user looking at the main page trying to sign up for the first time being redirected from the main page to a sign up form.

Comment: If you replaced "When I go the signup page" with "When I visit a restricted page" then it would make more sense. Otherwise it sounds like you're redirecting the user the page they're already on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I think it makes sense to have some reference to "I click the signup link" if that's how users will be accessing the form. Another question this scenario raises relates to the overall user journey - where will the user be in order to click that link?
To me, this scenario should document that aspect as well.

I'd also recommend keeping non-relevant technical terminology out of scenarios. A scenario should cover the most important aspects of a business rule or user journey from the perspective of the user to whom the user story concerns. Therefore from a user's perspective the term 'redirect' won't mean much and it's not important to them if the page was redirected or if they just followed a plain link.

You may wish consider something along this lines of :

```
Scenario: sign up
   Given I have not yet signed up
     And I am on the homepage
    When I click the signup link
    Then I should be on the signup page
```

Comment: Yea that explains better what I was trying to get at. Basically, user sitting at home page clicks the Sign up link and is brought to the sign up page. Also, are Cucumber User stories being relatively equivalent to UML use cases a correct analogy?